# Unable to load angularjs library

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing angularjs application. I was using below link to refer angularjs.

```
 <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.5" data-semver="1.4.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>
```

I am getting below error.  `https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

suddenly now i am not able to load this library. Is there any problem with angular site? Anyone else facing this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Love all the answers of *"CDN is down, use a CDN"* :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its always better to use bower and install the library which you want to use.

Use some package manager like **[`bower`](https://www.codementor.io/bower/tutorial/beginner-tutorial-getting-started-bower-package-manager)** to load your dependencies.

Don't rely on the cdn/library url , sometimes they update the url on anytime and it might get timed out.

Answer (score 2):

The given library link is not working.
Use the below cdn url :
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.js

Answer (score 1):

The hosted library is not loading, you can check it by directly accessing `https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js`

Use `src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"` instead.

Comment: Thank you. Worked like charm. May i know why this happened? I scratched my head for one hour!

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole do not rely on online libraries

Comment: its not a recommended way to use min.js file in production

Comment: It looks like the site `code.angularjs.org` is down, or something is wrong with that. Anytime if you think any of your library is not loading, try accessing them directly on the url box and check it. :)

Answer (score 1):

your CDN link is down for some reason. you can use the bellow link. It is better not to use the CDN. Try to use the downloaded file instead.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better you use a package manager like `bower` which would help to manage all dependent packages of your project and load them easily. A simple bower.json example i have provided below. It's better you avoid using online CDN hosted libraries.

```
{
  "name": "angular-seed",
  "description": "A starter project for AngularJS",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/angular/angular-seed",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.5.0",
    "angular-route": "~1.5.0",
    "angular-loader": "~1.5.0",
    "angular-mocks": "~1.5.0",
    "html5-boilerplate": "^5.3.0"
  }
}
```