# Angular is not loading, AngularJS website is down?

Tags: angular

Can anyone plz confirm, angularjs website is down?

```
https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js
```

I am using angularjs in my site and it is not working as angularjs script is not loading.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to load angularjs library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43730470/unable-to-load-angularjs-library)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because testing if a service is up is outside the scope of Stackoverflow questions.

Comment: To verify if a website is down you can use an external ping tool like [isup.me](http://www.isup.me/angularjs.org).

Comment: I am experiencing same problems. https://angularjs.org/ is not responsing at all. This should not be down voted!

Answer (score 4):

Instead you can use CDN for angularjs

```
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular.js/
```

Comment: This worked thanks! i used https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-resource.min.js instead of https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular-resource.min.js

Answer (score 2):

Yes, indeed the whole https://angularjs.org/ website is down.

Answer (score 0):

The link is not working for me either. It is better to use google CDN.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Change the version accordingly

Arun

Answer (score 0):

Most of the people use CDN for all kind of framework usage. So please use CDNs for Angular, Jquery, Bootstrap or any kind of frameworks.